# Storyboard with TabViewController in OS X Application - Core Data Array Controllers in each scene?

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data, swift

I am trying out Swift/XCode6 and its new Storyboard for OS X feature. So far everything works with one tab view controller three tab scenes and having all three of them connect back to core data through cocoa bindings and array controllers.
Is the official way to create one array controller per entity in each scene or is there an easier or perhaps more efficient and better way where I create them once and then point to them? Similar to what I do with my managedObjectContext which is created once in AppDelegate and then referenced in the various view controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct design is to have array controllers in each scene, to serve the needs of that scene.