# CoreData ArrayControllers in Cocoa Storyboards

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, uistoryboard, cocoa-bindings

I am developing the Mac OS port of an iOS App and do face a problem with NSManagedObjectContexts when using NSArrayControllers in the Storyboard based Cocoa app.

It's kind of a follow-up question to: 
[Storyboard with TabViewController in OS X Application - Core Data Array Controllers in each scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127362/storyboard-with-tabviewcontroller-in-os-x-application-core-data-array-controll#new-answer?newreg=60660e41c95649e9b44bafa767f3357b)

I do have some ViewControllers presented like in a TabBarController, showing the same CoreData Entities. They are loaded through NSArrayControllers, that are hooked up with InterfaceBuilder.

From my existing knowledge, it was no problem to get the data on the screens. Even editing and saving to CoreData works. 
But I realized, that every Storyboard scene got it's own instance of the NSArrayControllers and each its own NSManagedObjectContext.
When changing and saving the data on one screen, it is NOT updated on the other screens, that are all bound through the IB bindings and work in all other cases. They are just showing the data, they have loaded initially and are not updating automatically.

I think the problem is, that the changed data from contextA is not merged (or synced) to the other contexts of the other screens.

What is the best way of doing that? Should I use the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification for this?

That would mean, I would have to write much code, to manually start merging the changes from one context to all the other NSManagedContexts. Does smell really bad to me. I think there must be a much easier way, that I am not aware of and unable to find out about.

If you do have a hint for me, please just stick me in the right direction.
Thanks for that already.

Comment: Use one MOC. Bind each array controller to that one MOC.   You shouldn't have many if it's all main thread GUI stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In fact, I thought I did that, binding all ArrayControllers to the AppDelegate.moc, but when debugging the controllers, I see, that they all do have different MOC instances?!

Comment: Problem solved, I did a thumb error with Cocoa Bindings:   I just dragged an object in the storyboard to every scene and set that to the AppDelegate. I just instantiated several AppDelegates with this, very bad idea!   I corrected this, referencing the AppDelegate through properties on my ViewControllers and now it works as it should be.   IB just has its little edges, where one has to be totally aware, about what is happening. Thank you though for your comment, it led me to think about, where my problem is!

Comment: It's worth it to other users to answer your own question with links to other people who have had similar issues.  The app delegate object causes all sorts of grief, and it is difficult to debug.   I have seen this problem showing up more since storyboards were introduced to OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I did a thumb error with Cocoa Bindings: I just dragged an object in the storyboard to every scene and set that to the AppDelegate. I just instantiated several AppDelegates with this, very bad idea! I corrected this, referencing the AppDelegate through properties on my ViewControllers and now it works as it should be. IB just has its little edges, where one has to be totally aware, about what is happening.